# Append something to files that don't end with "]" recursively

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I am trying to append `[Full]` to all files that don't end with `]` in all subdirectories recursively.

Example:

`Untold Story.wav` should be renamed to `Untold Story [Full].wav`

`Untold Story [Instrumental].wav` should **not** be renamed to `Untold Story [Instrumental] [Full].wav`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script below should do the job. To use it:

1. Copy it into an empty file
2. Save it as `rename.py`
3. Run it by:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rename.py <directory_with_files>
   ```

#### The script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import shutil
import os
import sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for file in files:
        check = file.rfind("."); name = file[:check]
        print(name)
        if all([not name.endswith("]"), check not in (-1, 0)]):
            shutil.move(root+"/"+file, root+"/"+name+" [Full]"+file[check:])
```

#### What it does:

- It splits the file into basename + extension (all files inside a directory recursively)
- Sees if the basename ends with "]"
- If not, it adds " [Full]" to the basename, joins it with the extension and moves (renames) the file.
- Invisible files, or files without extension, are left alone.
- It works with all extensions

Comment: As expected from Jacob, works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: @BlackR You're welcome, and I feel honoured :)

Answer (score 3):

This will add `[FULL]` to the names of  all .wav whose names do *not* end in `].wav`:

```
find . -type f ! -name '*].wav' -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.wav} [FULL].wav"' none {} \;
```

#### How it works

- `find . -type f ! -name '*].wav'`

  This recursively finds all regular files under the current directory, `.`, whose names do not end in `].wav`.

  `-name '*].wav'` would look for files whose names end in `].wav`.  Since `!` is negation, `! -name '*].wav'` looks for all files whose names do *not* end in `].wav`
- `-exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.wav} [FULL].wav"' none {} \;`

  This renames the files that `find` found.

  This passes the name of the file into bash as its first argument, `$1`.  `mv` is used to rename the file.

Comment: There is a problem: `mv: cannot move ‘.’ to ‘. [FULL].wav’: Device or resource busy`

Comment: Try this: `find . -type f ! -name '*].wav' …`

Comment: @A.B. Yes, that does it.  Answer updated.

Comment: Thx and upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

And my version with `find`, `xargs` and `rename`

```
find . -type f -iname "*.wav" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} rename -v 's/^(.*[^\]])(\..*)/$1 [Full]$2/' {}
```

- The start is simple, `find …`, you can easy change the start (`.`) folder and the matching files (`*.wav`):

  Search in the current folder (`.`) for all files (`-type f`) with the extension `.wav` (`-iname "*.wav"`)
- Create a `rename` command with `xargs`

  The `{}` in `rename …` is replaced by the `find` results

Something Regular Expressions and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This will work only for files with a filename including an extension:

Using `find`+`xargs`+`rename`:

```
find . -type f -regex "^.*[^]]\..*$" -print0 | xargs rename -n "s/^(.*)(\..*)$/\$1 \[Full\]\$2/"
```

- `.` in `find`: lists all files and folders in the current working directory, recursively
- `-type f` in `find`: lists only files
- `-regex "[...]"`: lists only files with a filename matching the `[...]` regex
- `^.*[^]]\..*$`: matches any string not having a `]` character preceding the last `.` character
- `-print0` in `find`: prints filenames followed by a `NULL` character instead of a newline character
- `xargs`: passes each file's path to `rename`
- `-n` in `rename`: prints the changes without applying them
- `s/^(.*)(\..*)$/\$1 \[Full\]\$2/`: appends a `[Full]` string before the last `.` character to the filename

To apply the changes, remove the `-n` option from the `rename` command:

```
find . -type f -regex "^.*[^]]\..*$" -print0 | xargs rename "s/^(.*)(\..*)$/\$1 \[Full\]\$2/"
```

Comment: And an error: `Can't rename ./Untold  [Full]./Untold: No such file or directory
Can't rename Story.wav Story [Full].wav: No such file or directory`

Comment: @A.B. You're right, I wrote this with filenames with extension in mind. Let me see if I can rewrite this

Comment: @A.B. Anyway this is weird because the first regex just shouldn't match filenames with a `.`, so those should be discarded, and in fact that's what happens when I run it. Can you tell me which version of `find` are you running?

Comment: find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

Comment: But that's not the problem. The problem are the spaces in a filename: `find . -type f -regex "^.*[^]]\..*$"
./test 123.wav` –– `Can't rename 123.wav 123 [Full].wav: No such file or directory`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24326/discussion-between-a-b-and-kos).